# Download Debian 10

Tags: debian-cd

I've spent the last 30 or so minutes reading various pages on Debian that may be even remotely relevant to downloading, but I could not find a link to download Debian 10 x86-64 ISO image. I've gone trough links on https://www.debian.org/releases/ https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/ with no success as well as Wiki and some other links. 11 is available, but 10 is not even though it seems to be. Does anyone have a link to download 10?

Before you spend time responding that 11 is the current version to be used, consider that it occurs to me too but does not help.

Answer (score 3):

From [the Debian 10 page](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/), follow [the “installation information” link](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/debian-installer/) and you’ll find all the installers available for download, including [the `amd64` network installation image](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/10.12.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-10.12.0-amd64-netinst.iso) which is probably the one you’re after (x86-64 is `amd64` in Debian).